# Prolog predicate to multiply two lists (representing unary numbers)

Tags: list, prolog, successor-arithmetics

I want to write a code that multiplies lists representing a number, like: 
?- times([1,1,1], [1,1], Res). 
Res = [1,1,1,1,1,1].

```
times([], _, []). % base case
times([_|T], Lis, [Lis|H]) :-
  times(T, Lis, H).
```

I already have the code above and it kinda does what I want but not really. For example when asking: 
?- times([1,1,1], [1,1], Res) 
Res = [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]].

The idea is there, but I just don't know how to fix that, I understand why it's happening (I'm adding a list as head), so I just wondered if anybody could help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[Lis|H]` will use `Lis` as first element, regardless whether `Lis` is a list or not. You should take a look at `append/3` for example to append two lists.

Comment: These are Peano Numbers under a different form. Can you use append & friends or are you supposed to use Peano Number axioms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Lis|H]` will use `Lis` as first element, regardless whether `Lis` is a list or not. You should take a look at [**`append/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) for example to append two lists:

```
times([], _, []).
times([_|T], Lis, R) :-
    append(Lis, H, R),
    times(T, Lis, H).
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! It always makes sense when you see it, but coming up with it on your own... Thanks :)